# Software to plan a city trip

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for an app that will help me with planning a trip.

For example I'm going to NYC this weekend and I'll be walking around the city a lot and I also have a lot of places I'd like to visit. What I would like to do is put in the addresses of all of the places I want to go and have it organize them for me by distance and show me the walking and transit directions.

Let's say I start at point A and I have n number of addresses I want to visit: B,C,D,E,F...
It would look at the addresses and find the one that is closest to A, let's say it's C. So it would tell me directions from A to C. Then from C it would look at the list and tell me how to get to the next closest point etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for a program that can find the shortest path between a bunch of locations for you. I'd recommend trying the Travelling Salesman Problem Solver for Google Maps:

http://www.gebweb.net/optimap/